# Dealing with Dependent PySpark DataFrames

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a nested PySpark dataframe  `df`  with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- arr1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dt1: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dt2: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dt_indicator: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Suppose we have a process that flattens the nested dataframe in two flattened data frames  `df1`  and  `df2`  with the following schemas:

**df1 schema**

```
root
 |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a2: string (nullable = true)
```

and

**df2 schema**

```
|-- dt1: date (nullable = true)
|-- dt2: date (nullable = true)
|-- dt_indicator: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Is there a way of preserving the dependence of  `df2`  on  `df1` ? For example, if  `a1`  changes, then  `dt1`  and  `dt2`  might change. This would be easy to do in a single PySpark data frame. Can you do this using two flattened PySpark data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `df1` and `df2` are derived from `df` changes made to `df1` will not reflect on `df2`.

If you include a way to uniquely identify rows in `df` by introducting a [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html?highlight=monotonically#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) and including this ID across both `df1` and `df2` then you can use this `ID` to propagate conditions via a join.

That said, it would be benefical to apply dependent transformations on `df` and only then extract `df1` and `df2` to avoid un-necessary joins.